# Expresso Store: Larger, expandable text fields for modifiers

Tags: expresso-store, textarea, price-modifier

I'd like to make the custom text fields for the product modifiers in Exp:resso Store larger on the front end and user-expandable since they will need to type large amounts of text. Right now they are only one line high which makes it difficult to write a paragraph easily.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change any of the inputs to be textareas oppose to text inputs by doing something along the lines of:

```
{modifiers}
    <p>
      <label>{modifier_name}</label><br />
      {if modifier_instructions}<small>{modifier_instructions}</small><br />{/if}
      {if modifier_type == 'var' OR modifier_type == 'var_single_sku'}
        <select name="{modifier_input_name}">
          {modifier_options}
            <option value="{option_id}">
              {option_name}
              {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}
            </option>
          {/modifier_options}
        </select>
      {if:else}
        <textarea name="{modifier_input_name}"></textarea>
      {/if}
    </p>
  {/modifiers}
```